# 45lb Plate - At home workout Ideas

Tags: programs, home-exercise, routine, plates

I recently switched jobs and now the hours are pretty long and stressful. I still make time to workout in the morning for about a half hour every morning before I go to work.

The only things I really have access to are

- 45LB Weight Plate
- 2x 25lb Dumbbells

Now I have come a long way as far as strength, to the point that I'm not sure how much use I can get out of the dbs, so I'd like to focus on the 45lb Plate...
I was curious if anyone had any ideas on a solid full body workout routine that I could do maybe 3-4 times a week. I plan on mixing in HIIT on the days I don't strength train...

I am used to 5 x 5 powerbuilding programs which is nice but I think working with a 45LB plate will give me more functional strength oppose to just strength in those movements...so maybe stick to compound movements?

Any thoughts or ideas would be more than appreciated.

Comment: What is your goal?   If you add a goal, I think you will get more helpful answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the equipment, you can do a lot of brutal Complexes. They won't get your strength up like real strength workouts will, but you can build some muscle and drop a lot of fat.

Tuminello's weight plate complex is a good one to throw in your rotation.

Perform the complex five times with only 90 seconds rest between each round.

6-8 Overhead Squat
6-8 Kettlebell-like Swings
8-10 Bentover Row
4-5 per side Reverse Lunge and Twist
6-8 per side Diagonal Chops

There are several Complexes, with videos at the below link:

http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/sports_body_training_performance/screw_cardio_four_complexes_for_a_shredded_physique

You can also do most barbell Complexes with the dumbbells.

I second the recommendation for bodyweight strength training. Both zod and I make some recommendations here:

[I want to get ripped. Can bodyweight exercises do the job?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/16088/i-want-to-get-ripped-can-bodyweight-exercises-do-the-job)

Comment: Nice I'm going to try Tuminello's, thanks!

Comment: Good luck! I've never managed with more than a 25. Those twists kill me.

Answer (score 2):

If you've undergone strength building programs such as Strong Lift's 5X5, then, the only way you'll derive much benefits from a 45-lb plate is through high intensity and high repetitions/sets. While compound exercises are highly recommended, a lot of high repetitions/sets exercises are isolation movements *(which allows some parts of the body to rest while others are being activated)*. 
 
While there are many exercises that I can recommend, it would be better to follow a program. If you can lay your hands on P90X videos, there are many routines in it that you can perform with 25-lb dumbbells which will effectively work your muscles. Another program I've seen *(but haven't tried)* is the [Bizzy Diet](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/the-bizzy-diet.html). The intensity and reps of the program should work your muscles. 
 
And of course, my favorite exercises: body weight exercises. The only equipment you need is a pull up bar. Those can be done anywhere and are guaranteed to give you a very intense workout. Push ups, pull ups, chin ups, L-sit, legs up, reverse crunches, standing crunches, regular crunches, planks, etc. They are numerous and are guaranteed to give your body the workout of its life. 
 
Whatever you do, ensure you keep exercising ;).

Comment: exnay on the p90xnay...